# RavenDB String.Contains on multi map index

Tags: ravendb

So far I have an index like this:

```
public class Animals_Search : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Animals_Search.Result> {
    public class Result {
        public object[] Content { get; set; }
    }

    public Animals_Search() {
        AddMap<Dog>(a => from b in a select new Result { Content = new object[] { b.Name, b.Breed} });
        AddMap<Cat>(a=> from bin docs select new Result { Content = new object[] { b.Name, b.Breed} });

        Index(x => x.Content, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And a query like this:

```
session.Query<Animals_Search.Result, Animals_Search>()
    .Search(a => a.Content, match)                
    .As<Animal>()
    .ToList();
```

This works if I provide search terms like "Collie" or "Terrier", but not "Coll" or "Terr"

How do I rewrite the query to work something like String.Contains("Terr")?

Answer (score 1):

RavenDB make it hard to do contains query, because for the most part, they aren't needed.
What you probably want is to do a StartsWith, instead.

```
session.Query<Animals_Search.Result, Animals_Search>()
    .Where(a => a.Content.StartsWith(match))                
    .As<Animal>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because Content is an object[]. If I made it a string[] instead and did something likeContent.Any<string>(x => x.StartsWith(match)), how well would that play with the index?